# Is it possible to get the Total count in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have data as below , count is (e.g: the number of complex issues are created month wise), I also need to get the sum of the count here for all the 12 months based on the name in a single row, is it achievable?

Below is the query

```
WITH
PERIOD AS
(
   SELECT LEVEL LVL ,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), (LEVEL - 1)), 'MON YY') PERIOD_DATE ,ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), (LEVEL - 1)) PERIOD_DATE_RAW 
   FROM DUAL 
   CONNECT BY
   LEVEL < 13
)

,INCIDENTDATA AS
(
  SELECT COUNT(1) COUNT_OF,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() ,TRUNC(IMM.CREATED_DATE,'MON')CREATEDATE, IMM.CATEGORY_ID Category 
  FROM IN_INC IMM 
  GROUP BY TRUNC(IMM.CREATED_DATE,'MON'),IMM.CATEGORY_ID
)

,DUALL AS
(
  SELECT CAT.NAME NAME,CAT.ID ID FROM IN_IN CAT 
) 

,PERIODDATA AS
(
   SELECT PD.LVL,PD.PERIOD_DATE, DUALL.NAME,DUALL.ID,PD.PERIOD_DATE_RAW 
   FROM DUALL CROSS JOIN PERIOD PD
   ORDER BY DUALL.NAME ,PD.LVL
)

SELECT PRO.NAME,PRO.PERIOD_DATE,RD.COUNT_OF,count(I.ID)total 
FROM PERIODDATA PRO
LEFT OUTER JOIN INCIDENTDATA RD ON RD.CREATEDATE=PRO.PERIOD_DATE_RAW AND  PRO.ID=RD.Category 
LEFT OUTER JOIN IN_INC I ON  I.CATEGORY_ID = RD.Category  

GROUP BY PRO.NAME,PRO.PERIOD_DATE,RD.COUNT_OF,PRO.LVL
ORDER BY PRO.NAME, PRO.LVL,PRO.PERIOD_DATE
```

in The total column , i have a count(id) which im getting the count for 12 months but if you see the result set i have posted in my 1st post, the total repeats for each row, my question here is it possible to somehow display the total of 12months at one time ??

```
Name             Date   Count  total count

Complex     JAN 15          0
Complex     FEB 15          0
Complex     MAR 15          0
Complex     APR 15          0
Complex     MAY 15          1   3
Complex     JUN 15          1   3
Complex     JUL 15          1   3
Complex     AUG 15          0
Complex     SEP 15          0
Complex     OCT 15          0
Complex     NOV 15          0
Complex     DEC 15          0
Issue       JAN 15          0
Issue       FEB 15          0
Issue       MAR 15          0
Issue       APR 15          2   12
Issue       MAY 15          0
Issue       JUN 15          9   12
Issue       JUL 15          1   12
Issue       AUG 15          0
Issue       SEP 15          0
```

Comment: Which rdbms do you use?

Comment: `SELECT name, count(*) from my_table GROUP BY name;`

Comment: Hi, i need to get the total count (for all 12 months) gruoping by name and months, as in the above sample data set

Comment: What did you trie so far? Any effort to solve your problem would be nice (preferably with example code and description about where did you stuck..). Please read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: select name, sum(total_count) from table_name group by name;

Answer (score 1):

If `total_count` is not already created, and you are looking to create it:

```
SELECT name,date,count,SUM(count) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as total_count
```

Comment: Sorry, did not see you were using Oracle. Not sure if this works, this is for SQL Server

Comment: Hi Sam, It dint work, the total count is repeating for all 12 months

Comment: @newuser sorry should have been SUM, not COUNT. The only reason to use partition here is so that you can still include the date column. You might have to do some grouping though, not sure

Answer (score 0):

Here are an Example using **MS SQL**

```
SELECT MyTable.[Name], MyTable.[Date], MyTable.[Count], RefTable.TOTAL
FROM MyTable
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Name] AS RefName, SUM([Count]) AS TOTAL FROM MyTable GROUP BY [Name]) AS RefTable 
ON MyTable.[Name]= RefTable.RefName AND MyTable.[Count] > 0
```

and here a live Demo via [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67c9e/1).

I hope it is useful for you even if it is MS SQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name, SUM(total count) AS count_sum FROM your_table ORDER BY name
```

I think this is what you wanted

The `SUM()` function for SQL works well for your scenario